# Get URL parameters Angular 2, after #

Tags: angular

I have a problem when i try to get parameters from the url, 
the value of access_token variable for example is undifined ?

Example of the url (from a callback) :
http://localhost:4200/#access_token=1561651sdqs5dq5645646
My code 
under the constructor :

```js
  router.events.subscribe(s => {
      if (s instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        
        let params = new URLSearchParams(s.url.split('#')[1]);
        let access_token = params.get('access_token');
        let code = params.get('code');
      }
    });
```

Comment: and the problem is ?

Comment: the problem is the value of access_token is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get params :-

```
let access_token = this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
     console.log(params['access_token'], 'access token is')
});
```

where `route` here is

```
construcutor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

Comment: this is the result : NaN "access token is"

Comment: try by removing `+` sign before `params`

Comment: undefined "access token is"

Comment: probably your problem is somthing else than

Comment: This is my problem, with the "?" i can do it, but with the # i'm in a problem